# how to download video from my app to photos by react native on IOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I created function to download video from url to local storage by `rn-fetch-blob` library, it's working on android fine, but not working on ios 
i added persmission by xcode but when i open photos or camera roll i can't find video

```
 async download() {
        this.setState({btnDownloadLoading: true});

        const {video} = this.state;
        let hasPermission = await this.requestStoragePermission();

        console.log('hasPermission : ', hasPermission);
        if (!hasPermission) {
            this.requestStoragePermission();
            this.setState({btnDownloadLoading: false});
            return false;
        }

        var date = new Date();
        var url = video.video_url;
        var ext = this.extention(url);
        ext = "." + ext[0];
        const {config, fs} = RNFetchBlob
        let MovieDir = fs.dirs.DownloadDir
        let options = {
            fileCache: true,
            addAndroidDownloads: {
                useDownloadManager: true,
                notification: true,
                path: MovieDir + "/video_" + Math.floor(date.getTime() + date.getSeconds() / 2) + ext,
                description: 'Video'
            }
        }
        config(options).fetch('GET', url).then((res) => {
            this.setState({btnDownloadLoading: false});
            Alert.alert("تم تحميل الفيديو بنجاح.");
        });
    }
```

i need code that will work on ios and android to download video from url to my phone

Answer (score -1):

You can use cameraRoll for saving images .

```
 CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(filePath, 'photo')
                .then(Alert.alert('Success', ' added to camera roll!'))
```

It works for me.